# Breaking out of a loop from different class

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

So, this is what I have. This is a server program that connects to multiple clients by using threads. As of now, that main loop is pretty much infinite.
Say a client sent a shutdown command to a ServerThread. Would that ServerThread be able to access the main class, break out of the loop, and reach the end of the program?

I tried turning putting isRunning = false in the ServerThread, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
public class Server
{
    public static boolean isRunning = true; 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // init stuff

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27647);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            println("Could not listen on port 27647");
        }

        while(isRunning)
        {  
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try{
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                println("Could not connect to client"); 
            }

            ServerThread serv = new ServerThread(clientSocket);
            serv.start();
        }

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you put `isRunning = false` in ServerThread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make isRunning volatile and you have to close the serverSocket to unblock the accepting thread.  I suggest you have a method like

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    isRunning = false;
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

If you call this from any thread, the thread will stop almost immediately.

Comment: volatile ensures three things 1) the compiler will not optimise reads and writes 2) the CPU will not only access it's own copy in cache 3) there is a happens before and after relationship defined. i.e. any update you do before a volatile write will be visible and any read you do after a volatile read will see any write which was done before it.